# Disable passing of touches and gestures through MKMapView ViewController overlay

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, storyboard, mapkit

I have an MKMapView with a container view which holds a view controller that I'm using as an interactive legend. I can't seem to figure out how to have the view controller (a UITableViewController in actuality) behave normally to touches but not pass them to the map view. Right now it acts like it should except if you double tap in the legend, the map view zooms in. How can I have the table view controller intercept that and any other gestures and not pass them through to the map view?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'm doing to stop the map view moving around in a table cell:

```
mapCell.mapView.zoomEnabled = NO;
mapCell.mapView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Where mapCell is the cell in question and mapView is the MKMapView object showing the map.